# How do I install a volume control and support hardware buttons in Xfce on Gentoo?

Tags: audio, gentoo, xfce, alsa

I have got my audio card and `alsamixer` working on my Gentoo installation, as I'm too bored to visit that program all the time I need to make a subtle audio adjustment I'm looking forward to doing this with a volume control on my Xfce panel and/or the hardware audio keys just like I'm used to...

So... **How do I install a volume control in Xfce and get support for my hardawre buttons?**

I tried installing `xfce4-mixer` but I only seem to have an entry in `Applications > Multimedia` called `Mixer` which upon launching gives the following error:

> GStreamer was unable to detect any
>   sound devices. Some sound system
>   specific GStreamer packages may be
>   missing. It may also be a permissions
>   problem.

Although I do have audio working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
emerge xfce-extra/xfce4-volumed
```

If you have a volume knob or volume keys it should just work. you might also want:

```
emerge xfce-extra/xfce4-notifyd
```

To get a nice popup when you change volumes.

Comment: @nodisc: I get the error `Skipping unavailable plugin 'alsasink'` there.

Comment: @nodisc: `emerge gnome-media gst-plugins-alsa` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking the right question. Its not "in Gentoo" its in xfce or X.org

You can read a general guide here: [xfce special key bindings](http://darmawan-salihun.blogspot.com/2008/07/xfce-44-special-key-bindings.html)

Now, tell me that you're talking about laptop buttons and not the ones on your keyboard and ill link you to an acpi guide. As to the second part of your question Id recommend you add your user to the audio group, log out and then back in.

Comment: Keith disproves your statement, an `emerge` is handier than doing everything manually...

Comment: lol install ubuntu. If the dude above fails to find a package, then wtf can I do..

Comment: What can Ubuntu do for me? Why wouldn't a package be available? Why not follow the KISS principle?

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly rude. I apologize.